# Filtering array of objects with filter and underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

please check this code

```
    var arr = [{ name:"Toyota, minivan", id:"506", size: "large" }, { name:"Honda Moose", id:"619", size: "big" }, { name:"Honda Civic", id:"619", size: "mini" },{ name:"Honda Tree", id:"mini", size: "big" }];

var searchStr=['Toyota'];
var mini = _.filter(arr, function (obj) {
return _.values(obj).some(function (el) {
    return el.indexOf(searchStr) > -1;     
});
});
console.log(mini);
```

the data is filtering ok but what i want is if searchStr array has multiple values it doesnot work so how can do it using multiple vales in array of searchStr.something like

```
    var searchStr = ['Toyota','big'];
```

Comment: Please format and indent your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want `some` of the search strings to be part of `some` attribute. Or, if you want an exclusive search, you would use `_.every`, so that **every** search text appears in **some** attribute.

```
var cars = [...]

var searchInputs = ['Toyota','big'];
var mini = _.filter(arr, function (cars) {
    return _.values(obj).some(function (carAttribute) {
        return _.some(searchInputs, function(searchText){
            return carAttribute.indexOf(searchText) > -1;
        })    
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you its wat i'm looking.

Comment: Actually im using it in angular app i have a service call which will return data and store in some variable like data.items and if i give data.items it says  carAttribute is null. Can u help me